# permutations and combinations of [1, 2, 3, ..., n] elements for each of two vectors in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Perhaps this is the wrong way to say it, but I need all possible permutations of the combination of the elements of two vectors, using R. This is different from any question I could find.

The two vectors are always of equal length. Suppose we have these vectors (these are unique id numbers of cases in two dataframes somewhere):

```
vector1 <- 1:3
vector2 <- 1:3

nvec <- length(vector1)
```

What I want to end up with, is:

```
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    [1,2]
1    [1,3]
1    [2,3]
1    [1,2,3]
2    1
... and so on
```

And then it continues with two elements of the first vector:

```
[1,2]    1
[1,2]    2
[1,2]    3
[1,2]    [1,2]
[1,2]    [1,3]
[1,2]    [2,3]
[1,2]    [1,2,3]
[1,3]    1
... and so on
```

And so on, until it ends with:

```
[1,2,3]  [1,2,3]
```

How do I go about doing this sort of permutation plus combination for any given length of vectors? Sometimes I need to have all these combinations for vectors of length 2, but I also need it for vectors of length 10. (I realize my CPU may get a difficult time then.)

### ------------------

Here's what I've done so far:

To get one element from each vector, and get all permutations:

```
library(gtools)
res <- permutations(nvec, 2, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
res
     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    2    1
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    3    1
 [8,]    3    2
 [9,]    3    3
```

So the two columns represent the element number of the two original vectors, and they are all possible combinations of the two. Great.

But I also need all permutations of 2 elements of vector1 and 1 element of vector2.

```
# these are all unique combinations of the elements in vector1: three in total

combinations(nvec, 2) 

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
```

Of course I could have thought of (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3) by myself. But I would like to to this for larger vectors too, so then it becomes more difficult, and I need such a function.

So now I want to permute these three combinations of 2 elements of vector1 with 1 element in vector2. So the result should look like:

```
[1, 2]    1
[1, 2]    2
[1, 2]    3
[1, 3]    1
[1, 3]    2
[1, 3]    3
[2, 3]    1
[2, 3]    2
[2, 3]    3
```

And then do the same for all three elements of vector1 taken together, and 1 element of vector2, giving:

```
[1, 2, 3]  1
[1, 2, 3]  2
[1, 2, 3]  3
```

But I also need all permutations of 1 element of vector1 and 2 elements of vector2:

```
1   [1, 2] 
2   [1, 2] 
3   [1, 2] 
1   [1, 3] 
2   [1, 3] 
3   [1, 3] 
1   [2, 3] 
2   [2, 3] 
3   [2, 3]
```

And all combinations of two elements of each:

```
[1, 2]   [1, 2]
[1, 2]   [1, 3]
[1, 2]   [2, 3]  
[1, 3]   [1, 2]
[1, 3]   [1, 3]
[1, 3]   [2, 3]  
[2, 3]   [1, 2]
[2, 3]   [1, 3]
[2, 3]   [2, 3]
```

And then also all combinations of two elements of vector1 and all three elements of vector2, and the other way around, with three elements of vector1 and all combinations of two elements of vector2.

And finally I need to stitch it together (and sort). But perhaps I'm completely on the wrong track here.

Comment: So you want (I think) all combinations of the proper subsets of each vector. There are packages that "do" sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that results in a nested list:

```
# test vectors
vec1 <- 1:3
vec2 <- 4:6
# create all combinations of vector elements by length as nested list
comboList1 <- lapply(1:length(vec1), function(i) combn(vec1, i, simplify=FALSE))
comboList2 <- lapply(1:length(vec2), function(i) combn(vec2, i, simplify=FALSE))

# get fairly nested list of the Cartesian product of these lists
rapply(comboList1, function(i) rapply(comboList2, function(j) list(i, j), 
       how="list"), how="list")
```

As a cleaner reading list, you can use `unlist` as follows:

```
# use unlist the results of combn to simplify results
comboList1 <- unlist(comboList1, recursive=FALSE)
comboList2 <- unlist(comboList2, recursive=FALSE)
# now use lapply:
unlist(lapply(vec1, function(i) lapply(vec2, function(j) return(list(i, j)))), recursive=FALSE)
```

The final use of `unlist` flattens out the list, resulting in a two-level list where the second level is the comparison of vectors. This is as simplified as possible.

Comment: This will help get rid of some of the nestedness. 
`comboList1 <- do.call(c, lapply(lapply(1:length(vec1), function(x) combn(vec1, x)), function(x) split(x, rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x))))); 
comboList2 <- do.call(c, lapply(lapply(1:length(vec2), function(x) combn(vec2, x)), function(x) split(x, rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x))))); 
final <- do.call(c, lapply(comboList1, function(i) lapply(comboList2, function(j) list(i, j))))`

Comment: Thanks @fanli. I just realized this may be a great spot to use `rapply`. The results are much nicer looking than my previous results.

Comment: This solution, and this additional info works great! It's still a monster of a list, but I think I can make it work.

Comment: @lmo, how would you adjust it with rapply? Anything to get nicer looking results...

Comment: Thank you! I do find @fanli's solution easier to interpret. str(final) shows me a structure I understand immediately. But that's probably just me. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @graham.mcnamara. I wrapped the final output of the second method in `unlist`, which will result in a super-clean structure.